# retrieving ALL of my statuses

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve ALL of my facebook statuses using the graph api.

```
FB.api('/me/statuses?fields=message', function(response) {
            plot(response)
});
```

This code can retrieve only the last 25 statuses I've posted. So I tried with this:

```
FB.api('/me/statuses?fields=message&limit=100000', function(response) {
            plot(response)
});
```

and I still get a limited array (just 100 elements, while I know I posted more than 100 in my entire life).

Where can I find some explanation about this? The documentation seems not to talk about this limit: how does `limit` work?

Should I "turn" page and get another array of 100 statuses (and then repeat until I've finished) or is there anyway to get them all with just one call?

Comment: It's most likely a "feature" of the API.  Many public API's limit the number of results you get to keep someone from retrieving the entire interwebz in a single API call.  They *are* paying for the bandwidth, after all.

Comment: Did you look at the pagination links in the response for paging through the response?

Comment: Yes, but as I click them nothing happens! I still get the same 100 statuses. Not those which comes afterwards or before but just the same 100 (no matter if I click "previous" or "next").